# How to iterate nested data in laravel blade view?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have below the draft implementation. The spec is to show the parent information and children-grandchildren information.

```
@foreach ($parent as $children)
    <x-icons.chevron-right>
    <h1>{{ $parent->name }}</h1>
    
    @if($person->has('children'))
        // go back at the top for nested for each
    @endif
@endforeach
```

One solution that you may recommend is to create an iterative function. But my problem for that, it does not completely render my component-icon `chevron-right`.

```
@php
function showHTML($person) {
    $html = '';
    foreach($person as $children) {
        $html .= `
            <x-icons.chevron-right>
            <h1>$person->name</h1>
        `;
        
        if ($person->has('children')) {
            $html .= showHTML($person->children);
        }
    }
    return $html;
}
@endphp

{!! showHTML($person) !!}
```

---

Just wondering if you guys have other solution for this to show nested with a component icon? I would appreciate any answer.

Comment: Why do you loop over the data within `@php ... @endphp`? That completely defeats the purpose of blade templates unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply re-iterate the component if it has a children. In this case, the icon will be rendered properly.

So my usage would like this below:

```
<x-parent person="$person"></x-parent>
```

And my root component `parent.blade.php`. So If there is person has children I just re-iterate the component and pass his children as a prop:

```
@props(['person'])

<x-icons.chevron-right>
<h1>{{ $person->name }}</h1>

@if($person->has('children'))
  <x-parent person="$person->children"></x-parent>
@endif
```

Comment: this one is much shorter than mine :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try `=> value` on your foreach, that will fetch data array value from backend.
Or can you show your code on backend (controller), that can easy to help you

```php
@foreach ($parent as $children => $value)
    <x-icons.chevron-right>
    <h1>{{ $parent->name }}</h1>
    <h3>{{ $value->data }}<h3>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Could you please provide a code snippet that makes your solution more clear?

Comment: `@foreach ($parent as $children => $value)
    <x-icons.chevron-right>
    <h1>{{ $parent->name }}</h1>
<h3>{{ $value->data }}<h3>
@endforeach`

Comment: May I watch your backend code? it can be more easily to help you